# parse textbox value to variable defined in web method in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

Suppose I have a textbox1 which has some values e.g. Date. Now I have another textbox2 which has autocompleteextender and it's values called through web method defined. Now I want variable defined inside webmethod should get value from textbox1.

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(), System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static List<string> SearchVehicles(string prefixText, int count)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString;
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT flightNo FROM flight_train where (freq like @freq) and status = 'active'";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@freq", "%" + prefixText + "%");
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    List<string> strVehicle = new List<string>();
    MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader;
    while (sdr.Read) {
        strVehicle.Add(sdr("flightNo").ToString);
    }
    conn.Close();
    return strVehicle;
}
```

In above webmethod a variable (prefixText) is defined which I want to take value from textbox1

Comment: You have to pass the textbox1 value in the call of SearchVehicles from javascript / JQuery .

Comment: @Adil Can you please share a reference link or post it on answer how to do that?

Comment: @Adil Is it possible to store textbox1 value in session or viewstate & then retrieve that value in webmethod?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use ajax method in javascript to do that.In this webmethod you cannot access the form fields.

Comment: Is it possible to store textbox1 value in session or viewstate & then retrieve that value in webmethod?

Comment: yes you can use Sessions .
`HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionName"].ToString()`